# What is the correct way to create a cocos2dx project using "create_project.py" and place it under version control, and access via Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git, cocos2d-x

Normally, when you create a project through Xcode, you receive the option of having Xcode place the project under version control.

With cocos2dx, one creates a project by using the "create_project.py" tool, which basically created a number of folders for each platform (iOS, OSX, Android, WP8 etc). When you open the xcodeproj in the "iOS" folder, everything works fine in Xcode. But I can't get it to work after adding to version control. Here is what I did:

All these folders are placed under a root folder, which is the name of your project (lets call it "stanly"

```
stanly
    |->Classes
    |-> proj.ios
    |-> proj.mac
    |-> proj.android
    .....
    |->resources
```

Each of the above "proj.

Here is what I tried:

I opened a terminal under stanley, and ran the following commands:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

It appears that all the files in every subfolder has been added to version control.

In Xcode, I then went to "source control"-->"Connect to repository" , and pointed to the folder where I "init" the repository. I am asked which xcodeproj file to open, and a directory to use. I select "iOS" , and choose a new directory (not the one which the python script created)

The problem is, create_project.py, creates some kind of reference to cocos2dx in the xcodeproj file, but does not actually store the files in the same project directory! It is intact pointing at the cocos2dx project in the folder two folders above where "stanley" was created. So when you open the project through the repository, the "cocos2dx" xcodeproj file appears as "missing" and the project won't compile. This problem is not there if you open the proj.ios xcodeproj file directly (not by connecting to the repository through xcode).

How do I fix this ?

EDIT - If I change the path to where the file is actually stored, the cocos2dx xcodeproj file is no longer missing, but other similar errors show up.

**So what is the correct way, to create a cocos2dx project with create_project.py, place it under version control, and be able to add / commit / revert etc from the xcode guy?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating the git repository, Xcode automatically detects it, so there is no need to "connect" to the repository. You can directly edit the files / add / commit etc.